# QGraphicsSimpleTextItem antialiasing doesn't work

Tags: c++, qt

I set text to my `QGraphicsSimpleTextItem` which is in `QGraphicsItem` and seems that text antialiasing is not working or work very bad. I tried to set

```
font.setStyleStrategy(QFont::StyleStrategy::PreferAntialias);
```

and have override

```
void MyClass::paint(QPainter* painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem* option, QWidget* widget)
{
    painter->setRenderHints(painter->renderHints() | QPainter::Antialiasing | QPainter::TextAntialiasing | QPainter::HighQualityAntialiasing);
    QGraphicsItem::paint(painter, option, widget);
}
```

but text is still the same.

[image]

Comment: Can you share a complete and verifiable example with us? How can us reproduce the problem?

Answer (score 1):

My `paint()` function was done with help of **OpenGL**. I just created surface format without supporting multisampling for antialiasing. I had to write:

```
QSurfaceFormat sf = QSurfaceFormat::defaultFormat();
sf.setSamples(4);
```